# Plot histogram of the column pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

```
haversine = 

id_easy            meters
0   d14e    140885.533614
1   6024    136171.294532
2   8624    133870.080496
3   782f    133171.023674
4   7a0bc   132869.407625
```

Plotting histogram:

```
haversine.hist(column='meters',bins=50)
```

Output:
[image: a column]

Is it right? Max value is `140885` meters. But I can not see soething like that on plot

OR how to choose the range from 0 to 200000

Comment: I feel like the problem is that you only have few occurrences of the really big values, so the height of histogram at those points are so low that you don't see them. Try `log_scale` when you plot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by Michael you could try:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
haversine.hist(column='meters', bins=50, ax=ax)
ax.set_yscale('log')
```

If this doesn't give the answer you expect I suggest you try manually extracting the number of events you expect, count number of rows with greater than 140000 with

```
haversine[haversine['meters']>140000].shape[0]
```